# Android partial download http

Tags: android, https, download, partial

In my application I download media from server via HTTP connection. While downloading if connection is break anyhow (say, no n/w, permission revoke), File get downloaded partially.

Earlier we are deleting the file and downloading it from the scratch.

Now, the requirement is changed. I have to continue from where I left (like in WhatsApp).

So what I am doing is checking the file existence and if file exist skip the stream. Please find the below code snip.

```
InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

File file = new File(targetPath);
boolean fileExist = file.exists();
if (fileExist) {
    long skippedBytes = is.skip(file.length()); 
}

// opens an output stream to save into file
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(targetPath, fileExist);
```

Its working merely in respect of skipping but actually not working.

Say, file (video) length is 20 sec and in first attempt I downloaded up to 6 sec and rest subsequently. But when I play it just play till 6 sec then after throw the usual Video playback error.

Comment: using `InputStream.skip` doesn't make sens ... it still would be downloaded but skipped ... if server supports Range header I would rather use it

Comment: @Selvin, I know this will not save bandwidth but it should work. To save bandwidth we need to skip at server end. I am trying to implement at client end (not worry about bandwidth) using skip.

Comment: I would rather use the http header `Range`, if it is supported backend side

Comment: And about the "6 sec problem" - it that if app crash previously file may have some junk bytes at the end(can be corrupted) ... so it would be better to have another file (or Shared preferences) to store real count of saved data which would be written after you save chunk ... I would rather not depend on file length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
File file = new File(targetPath);

if (file.exists()) {
    con.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + (file.length()) + "-");
} else {
    con.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=" + 0 + "-");
}
```